# Unable to create a MozillaBrowserBot object

Tags: javascript, selenium, xul

I tried to get the MozillaBrowserBot object in mozilla js. But it is not giving the object. I used the code as below:

```
function externalApplication(){
        var wm = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Components.interfaces.nsIWindowMediator);
        alert("wm: "+wm);
        var contentWindow=wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser').getBrowser().contentWindow;
        alert("contentWindow: "+contentWindow);

        //I am not gettting this pageBot object
        var pagebot=new MozillaBrowserBot(contentWindow);
        alert(pagebot);
}
```

I want to add the find option to the xpath checker. If the MozillaBrowserBot is related to selenium IDE then is there any possibility to get the pagebot object?

Comment: The title is supposed to be a short summary, not to put the whole question in there. And the question body offers you lots of space to explain - like what `MozillaBrowserBot` is supposed to be so that we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 0):

Judging by Google search results, `MozillaBrowserBot` is something that's defined by Selenium IDE. Also, it is apparently defined in the content page you got, not in the context where your code executes. That means that the proper invocation would be:

```
var pagebot = new contentWindow.MozillaBrowserBot(contentWindow);
```

This is based on a bunch of guesses of course since your question doesn't provide any context information whatsoever.